# EXC_BAD_ACCESS When Using Core Data and Changing Values

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, core-data, memory

I am relatively new to Obj-C and CoreData. I have successfully used CoreData in the past but I am getting a problem when I try to assign values to the attributes in one of my managedObjects.

So, where I am is that I have instantiated my managedObjectContext and have created a managedObject to save out.

```
if (managedObjectContext == nil) 
    { 
        managedObjectContext = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]; 
    }

Lesson *Lesson1 = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Lesson" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
```

I then go to edit the values of the managedObject and save it out:

```
Lesson1.productID = 1;
    Lesson1.purchaseStatus = 1;
    Lesson1.title = @"Happy Birthday to You";
    Lesson1.subtitle = @"Patty & Mildred Hill";
    Lesson1.titleAndSubtitle = @"Happy Birthday to You - Patty & Mildred Hill";
    Lesson1.coverArtFilename = @"beethoven.png";
    Lesson1.durationLabel = @"0:11";
    Lesson1.notes = @"123";
    Lesson1.timing = @"3/4";
    Lesson1.keySignature = @"G";
    Lesson1.difficultyImageFilename = @"easy.png";
    Lesson1.lessonDescription = @"Originally, this song piece was called 'Good Morning to All' and was sung to and by children in school.";
    Lesson1.sheetFilename = @"1_score";
    Lesson1.midiFilename = @"happyBirthdayToYou";
    Lesson1.materialsFilename = @"1_score";
    Lesson1.roll = @"happyBirthdayToYou";
    Lesson1.duration = 11;
    Lesson1.startingIndicatorPosition = 175;
    Lesson1.rollPositionArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:   /* 0 */ [NSNumber numberWithInteger:0],
                                                             /* 1 */ [NSNumber numberWithInteger:0],    
                                                             /* 2 */ [NSNumber numberWithInteger:0],
                                                             /* 3 */ [NSNumber numberWithInteger:-65],
                                                             /* 4 */ [NSNumber numberWithInteger:-100],
                                                             /* 5 */ [NSNumber numberWithInteger:-135],
                                                             /* 6 */ [NSNumber numberWithInteger:-185],
                                                             /* 7 */ [NSNumber numberWithInteger:-185],
                                                             /* 8 */ [NSNumber numberWithInteger:-241],
                                                             /* 9 */ [NSNumber numberWithInteger:-306],
                                                             /* 10 */ [NSNumber numberWithInteger:-341],
                                                             /* 11 */ [NSNumber numberWithInteger:-376],
                                                             /* 12 */ [NSNumber numberWithInteger:-426],
                                                             /* 13 */ [NSNumber numberWithInteger:-426],
                                                             /* 14 */ [NSNumber numberWithInteger:-483],
                                                             /* 15 */ [NSNumber numberWithInteger:-548],
                                                             /* 16 */ [NSNumber numberWithInteger:-582],
                                                             /* 17 */ [NSNumber numberWithInteger:-617],
                                                             /* 18 */ [NSNumber numberWithInteger:-666],
                                                             /* 19 */ [NSNumber numberWithInteger:-701],
                                                             /* 20 */ [NSNumber numberWithInteger:-737],
                                                             /* 21 */ [NSNumber numberWithInteger:-799],
                                                             /* 22 */ [NSNumber numberWithInteger:-834],
                                                             /* 23 */ [NSNumber numberWithInteger:-868],
                                                             /* 24 */ [NSNumber numberWithInteger:-918],
                                                             nil];

    NSError *error;
    if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
```

At this point, if I run the application it gives me the error: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x1) when trying to change the value of the productID. It also gives me a warning stating that it is an "Incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to "int *" from "int".

I have done some debugging and checked to see if any of my objects are nil and they aren't. When I output the description of my managedObjectContext I get:

```
Printing description of self->managedObjectContext:
<NSManagedObjectContext: 0x7e8d8b0>
```

And printing my object, I get:

```
Printing description of Lesson1:
<NSManagedObject: 0x7e927e0> (entity: Lesson; id: 0x7e7fce0 <x-coredata:///Lesson/tA7BFE664-F978-4983-B5DC-14D3F3ED49812> ; data: {
    coverArtFilename = nil;
    difficultyImageFilename = nil;
    duration = 0;
    durationLabel = nil;
    keySignature = nil;
    lessonDescription = nil;
    materialsFilename = nil;
    midiFilename = nil;
    productID = nil;
    purchaseStatus = 0;
    roll = nil;
    rollPositionArray = nil;
    sheetFilename = nil;
    startingIndicatorPosition = 0;
    subtitle = nil;
    timing = nil;
    title = nil;
    titleAndSubtitle = nil;
})
```

My debugging skills are limited due to the little knowledge I have so if someone could point me in the right direction I would be very grateful. Thank you.

**EDIT**

My NSManagedObjectContext was defined in the default way. I've attached my AppDelegate.m below:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize managedObjectContext = __managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = __managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = __persistentStoreCoordinator;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
    [self saveContext];
}

- (void)saveContext
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        } 
    }
}

#pragma mark - Core Data stack

// Returns the managed object context for the application.
// If the context doesn't already exist, it is created and bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    if (__managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return __managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        __managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [__managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    return __managedObjectContext;
}

// Returns the managed object model for the application.
// If the model doesn't already exist, it is created from the application's model.
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (__managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return __managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"iLessons_Piano" withExtension:@"momd"];
    __managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return __managedObjectModel;
}

// Returns the persistent store coordinator for the application.
// If the coordinator doesn't already exist, it is created and the application's store added to it.
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (__persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"iLessons_Piano.sqlite"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    __persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {
        /*
         Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

         abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 

         Typical reasons for an error here include:
         * The persistent store is not accessible;
         * The schema for the persistent store is incompatible with current managed object model.
         Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.


         If the persistent store is not accessible, there is typically something wrong with the file path. Often, a file URL is pointing into the application's resources directory instead of a writeable directory.

         If you encounter schema incompatibility errors during development, you can reduce their frequency by:
         * Simply deleting the existing store:
         [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:storeURL error:nil]

         * Performing automatic lightweight migration by passing the following dictionary as the options parameter: 
         [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption, [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];

         Lightweight migration will only work for a limited set of schema changes; consult "Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration Programming Guide" for details.

         */
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }    

    return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

#pragma mark - Application's Documents directory

// Returns the URL to the application's Documents directory.
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isn't productID or any other numeric properties `NSNumber*`? Could you try

```
Lesson1.productID = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
```

Same for `purchaseStatus`, `duration` and `startingIndicatorPosition`

Comment: I tried that before but it said that it was an incompatible conversion between "NSNumber *" and "int *" :(

Comment: so those properties are defined as `int *`? How did you generate the NSManagedObject class? It should be `NSNumber*` if you defined those attributes as `Integer`.

Comment: I've posted my AppDelegate.m to show how my NSManagedObjectContext was generated. In my model I have defined the productID attribute as an "Integer 32".

Comment: I tried enabling NSZombies, NSAutoreleaseFreedObjectCheckEnabled, and NSDebugEnabled under "Edit Scheme" and the "Run" scheme but it never gave me any console output. I also tried doing a "Profile" with the zombies template but it just crashes out and doesn't raise a flag...

Comment: Oh, I think I misunderstood what you were asking before about generating the NSManagedObject class. I have created a Lesson.h and Lesson.m and simply declared my variables within (ie. @property int productID;) and then synthesized them in the .m file.

Comment: Oh my god...It was that simple. I changed my declaration to NSNumber in my object class and it worked...gah...thank you mask8 :)

Comment: glad it worked out. There is a specific way to generate NSManagedObject classes and you don't have to write it manually. maybe this tutorial helps http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started